# Extracting value from HTML table and applying assertion

Tags: webdriver, testng, assertions

I am trying to extract a value which is in integer form i.e 60.
I have a code that is going through each row and each column and then using `getText()` method retrieve the value from column.

When applying testNG assertEqual,the value is not matched as the value found is "[60 ]" instead of "[60]".

Output of trace: 
`The Text is 60`

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError: expected [60] but found [60 ]
    at org.testng.Assert.fail(Assert.java:94)
    at org.testng.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:494)
    at org.testng.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:123)
    at org.testng.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:165)
    at rough.Test.main(Test.java:83)`

Can someone help me finding how I can fix the assertion?

Comment: Could you please publish your assertion code?

Comment: Can you show your html? That will show for certain exactly what the value really is.

Answer (score 0):

do you in fact have a trailing space in the table? 
this is an issue that is good to find in testing
perhaps you should trim the result of getText()

Comment: Thanks everyone,the solution provided by Logan worked fine.

Thanks again for help.

Comment: lol his answer is the same as what i said to do ... but ok glad you got it to work

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because your code looks something like this`<td>60 </td>`

You are getting that extra space. You can try something like this.

```
String s = node.getText().trim();
assertEqual(s, "60");
```

Comment: Hi Logan,Thanks for the answer,when i use trim(),still getting the following

The Text is 60
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError: expected [60] but found [60]
 at org.testng.Assert.fail(Assert.java:94)
 at org.testng.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:494)
 at org.testng.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:123)
 at org.testng.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:165)
 at rough.Test.main(Test.java:83

Comment: @Mani: If you've found a working solution, you should accept the answer to show that you're no longer waiting for more answers. Also, it gives Logan Murphy their due credit.